# SSO CAS PHP errror : CAS\Request\CurlRequest.php on line 105

Tags: php, single-sign-on, cas

I got a problem when I configure the single-sign-on on a php system.
Error message come out after I submited the username and pass.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in D:\MYOA\webroot\CAS\Request\CurlRequest.php on line 105

Could you tell me how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means I should add the module **php_curl.dll** in the **php.ini** file.
You should pay attention to the version of **php_curl.dll**.tips:You could check the version of other dll in the extension folder.